# Table of Contents does not work correctly

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, table-of-contents

I made three different headings, one for each numbering level. For example "1. Topic" will be always Heading 1, "1.1 Topic" will be always Heading 2 and "1.1.1 Topic" will be always Heading 3.

**Table of contents**: 
[image]

**Options**:
[image]

As you can see Table of Contents goes to 1.2.1 instead of 1.1.2 for some reason, and everything else is messed up.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Yes, this one indeed solved my problem! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I was using this guide: http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/word-2007-taming-multilevel-list-numbering/

I followed only Step 1 (30 paragraphs), which was enough for me to multilevel numbering to work. I think the main problem I missed when doing it first time is I didn't put my cursor in FRONT of grayed number when selecting from "Include level number from" drop-down list.